# $A=\frac{a}{7}+\frac{b}{7^2}+\frac{c}{7^3}+\frac{d}{7^4}$ where all variables are (0-6)

Tags: permutations, contest-math

> Let $A=\frac{a}{7}+\frac{b}{7^2}+\frac{c}{7^3}+\frac{d}{7^4}$ where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are non-negative integers less than or equal to $6$. If you list out the possible values of $A$ in descending order, what is the $2018$<sup>th</sup> number on the list.

I didn't bother finding the exact values of $A$. I just grouped together the digits $a,b,c,d$ into a single number $\overline{abcd}$, and then tried ordering them like this:

1. $6666$
2. $6665$
   and so on...

Serials: $1,2,3,4,5,6 \rightarrow 666-$ Numbers ($6-1$) fill the blank.

$7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 \rightarrow665-$

I'm confused whether $0$ is a possible value for the variables and I need to add another element into my current set of 6 numbers. There also was a Bengali version of this problem, and that seems to say these are counting numbers.

Anyways, then I did $2018/6=336$ and $2018\mod6=2$,

which means $d$ is $5$.

The last digit of $336$ subtracted from 6 from probably gives $c$, the second last subtracted from 6 giving $b$, and so on...

But I'm not really sure and I need some help on this one.

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying the given expression, we see that

$$A=\frac{7^3a+7^2b+7c+d}{7^4}$$

Clearly, the numerator can be any integer from $0$ to $7^4-1$. In fact, for any integer $n$ in this range, just set $a,b,c,d$ according to the unique representation of $n$ in base $7$. And this is also a bijection since any values of $a,b,c,d$ from $0-6$ will give you an integer in the desired range.

Importantly, this bijection between integers in $[0,7^4-1]$ and values of $A$ preserves the ordering. Therefore in descending order, the $n$th value of $A$ is just $\frac{7^4-n}{7^4}$. Simply plug in $n=2018$ to get your answer.

Comment: Thanks! Do u have any comment on my method of arranging it?

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine You were definitely on the right track. You just needed to notice that the numerator corresponds to numbers in base $7$. Also, 0 is a possible value for $a,b,c,d$ because 0 is nonnegative.

Comment: I really don't understand how the max value of $A$ is 7^4-1.

Comment: The max value of $A$ is actually $\frac{7^4-1}{7^4}$. The max value of the *numerator* is $7^4-1$. This is because $7^4$ is the first natural number  that requires a fifth digit to be expressed in base $7$.

Another way of thinking about it is that the max values for $a,b,c,d$ are all $6$. So if you plug in $6$ for $a,b,c,d$ you actually get $7^4-1$ in the numerator.

Comment: Oh, I see. $7^3a+7^2b+7c$ is at least smaller than $7^4$. Even the extra $d$ added with it doesn't make it equal to $7^4$???

Comment: $7^3\cdot 6 + 7^2\cdot 6+7\cdot 6+6=7^4-1$. And each $a,b,c,d$ cannot exceed $6$, so this is our maximum value for the numerator.